# WordPress Multisite with NGINX, subfolders, and FROM a subfolder

Tags: multisite, nginx

Dear fellow WordPress enthusiasts,

I am using WordPress multisite. The default blog works, with permalinks, but not the subblogs. I get a redirect loop when trying to access /wp-admin on a network site.

I am using FastCGI with Facebook's HHVM; similar to plain vanilla FastCGI.

I know I am missing server blocks to redirect files: I want, first and foremost, to understand why I'd get a redirect loop on sub-sites.

Thank you for your help.

My nginx configuration is as follows:

```
# You may add here your
# server {
#   ...
# }
# statements for each of your virtual hosts to this file

##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
# http://wiki.nginx.org/QuickStart
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
#
# Generally, you will want to move this file somewhere, and start with a clean
# file but keep this around for reference. Or just disable in sites-enabled.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name whatever.com;
    # include hhvm.conf;

    # Rewrite multisite '.../wp-.*' and '.../*.php'.
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;
        rewrite ^/[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+(/wp-.*) $1 last;
        rewrite ^/[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+(/.*\.php)$ $1 last;
    }

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ /labs/index.php?$args;
        # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
        # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }


    location ~ \.(hh|php)$ {

        try_files $uri /labs/index.php;
        fastcgi_keep_conn on;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~* ^.+\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
        access_log off; log_not_found off; expires max;
    }

    location = /robots.txt { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location ~ /\. { deny  all; access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    # Only for nginx-naxsi used with nginx-naxsi-ui : process denied requests
    #location /RequestDenied {
    #   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;    
    #}

    #error_page 404 /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    #error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    #location = /50x.html {
    #   root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #   fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    #   # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
    #
    #   # With php5-cgi alone:
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #   # With php5-fpm:
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    #   fastcgi_index index.php;
    #   include fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}


# another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
#
#server {
#   listen 8000;
#   listen somename:8080;
#   server_name somename alias another.alias;
#   root html;
#   index index.html index.htm;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}


# HTTPS server
#
#server {
#   listen 443;
#   server_name localhost;
#
#   root html;
#   index index.html index.htm;
#
#   ssl on;
#   ssl_certificate cert.pem;
#   ssl_certificate_key cert.key;
#
#   ssl_session_timeout 5m;
#
#   ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # don't use SSLv3 ref: POODLE
#   ssl_ciphers "HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5 or HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!3DES";
#   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}
```

Comment: What are your values for the constants `DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE`, `PATH_CURRENT_SITE` and `SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE`. Does they match with the domain/path column of the `wp_blogs` table for this ID? Do they further match the `home` and `siteurl` option for that specific blog (table `wp_$ID_options`)? I never worked with NGINX but from my perspective the rewrite patterns are okay.
Do you have any error logs for that redirection loop?

Answer (score 5):

Actually, I solved it thanks to this reference:
https://rtcamp.com/wordpress-nginx/tutorials/multisite/subdirectories/in-a-subdirectory/

With the root directory of the installation being "labs" in my case, the final nginx configuration file looks like:

```
# You may add here your
# server {
#   ...
# }
# statements for each of your virtual hosts to this file

##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
# http://wiki.nginx.org/QuickStart
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
#
# Generally, you will want to move this file somewhere, and start with a clean
# file but keep this around for reference. Or just disable in sites-enabled.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name whatever.com;
    # include hhvm.conf;

    # Rewrite multisite '.../wp-.*' and '.../*.php'.
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;
        rewrite ^/labs(/[^/]+)?(/wp-.*) /labs$2 last;      
        rewrite ^/labs(/[^/]+)?(/.*\.php)$ /labs$2 last;
    }


    location /labs/ {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ /labs/index.php?$args;
    }


    location ~ \.(hh|php)$ {
        try_files $uri /labs/index.php;
        fastcgi_keep_conn on;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~* ^.+\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
        access_log off; log_not_found off; expires max;
    }

    location = /robots.txt { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location ~ /\. { deny  all; access_log off; log_not_found off; }


}
```

And it works just fine. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Worked fine for me also! Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.